Is this recurrence relation decreasing?
In a previous question (What can be said about this recurrence relation?), I described a recurrence relation and asked for the limit. Here, I am reducing the scope to just ask if I can prove a monotonicity inequality. Fix a positive integer $N$ and a fix $\delta \in (0,1)$. A sequence $v_k$ is described by an initial value $v_N = 0$ and the quadratic recurrence relation
$$
v_{k} = v_{k+1} - \frac{(\delta^k+v_{k+1})(\delta^{k-1}+v_{k+1})}{\delta^{k-1} (2+\delta)} = \frac{-\delta^{1-k} v_{k+1}^2 + v_{k+1} - \delta^k}{2+\delta}
$$
I know that $v_{k} \in [-1,0]$ regardless of $N$ and $k$, and it is easy to show that $v_{k} < \frac{v_{k+1}}{2+\delta}$ because the quadratic and constant terms are negative.
Is it possible to prove that $v_k < v_{k+1}$ (for $0 \le k \le N$)? It seems to be true experimentally. If it happens to fail for some particular small values of $k$, that is fine.
